# Drupal 7 White Screen of Death when adding content type

Tags: wsod

When I navigate to /?q=admin/structure/types/add in order to add a content type, I get a white screen of death.
I'm running Drupal version 7.41 on Windows 2008 r2.
Can someone walk me through the steps on diagnosing this problem? Most of the documentation I've found is written for the Linux platform, so it's not very helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Which ones? The web server logs? The windows system logs?

Comment: `.../admin/reports/dblog`

Comment: There are no errors in the log. I actually cleared the log, went to the page then checked the log again. There is absolutely nothing there.

Comment: Hi Jim, we can't give you any more specific advice here than on your [almost identical question elsewhere on the network](http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/7737/internal-server-error) - this is something that needs to be debugged by someone with access to the machine

Comment: I appreciate your time and attention. I would argue the questions are not almost identical. One is related to a problem I'm having with civicrm specifically. This one is related to Drupal in general.

Comment: I probably didn't explain that too well, sorry - what you need to know, i.e. "what do I do next?", isn't Drupal or Civi or any PHP application specific - the very first thing you need when you see a white screen in a PHP application, is to find the server logs (that might be apache logs if you're on apache, fpm logs if you're using that, IIS maybe, something else, only you'll know), and see what the fatal error is that caused the script to die. Without that it's literally "I have an error, how do I fix it?", which just isn't the right type of question for Q+A

Comment: Just to address the edit: none of the other questions are about Linux - on the duplicate, 2 of 4 questions have Unix-y solutions, but the other 2 of 4 don't - they can be used in any PHP installation, on any platform. It's likely what you need to find is out is where your error logs are stored - that isn't something any Drupal knowledge can help with, it's down to how you've configured the server. A quick Google with keywords related to your installation type will clear it up, and when you have a specific error, edit this question or just ask a new one and someone may be able to help further